# String empty from xPath element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need help with this problem:

I need to extract the text from this xPath to a string, but for some reason I can't!

my code:

```
string caseTitle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[1]/div/h2'")).Text;
           
Assert.AreEqual(caseTitle, "Hey, Extract this String!");
```

[xPath expect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdbuo.png)

Comment: what is driver here ?

Comment: chromedriver/seleniumwebdriver

Comment: It is not getting that text?

Comment: No, its returning a empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract exactly that text, So you could use this XPath

```
//h2[text()='Hey, Exctract this String!']

OR

//*[text()='Hey, Exctract this String!']
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a `'` extra at the end of `h2`.

```
string caseTitle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[1]/div/h2")).Text;
Console.WriteLine(caseTitle);
Assert.AreEqual(caseTitle, "Hey, Extract this String!");
```

May be we need to tweak xpath also, (if the above does not work, try the below one)

```
//div[contains(@class, 'col-title')]//h2
```